# tools or a website to help with database normalization

Tags: sql, normalization

Are there any tools or online resources (FREX tutorials) that would help a neophyte with database normalization?

Comment: Normalisation should not require a tool.

Comment: @The Machine Charmer: because as the database designer you should understand what you are modelling with respect to the domain.

Comment: How about stackoverflow? I hear the people over there are pretty supportive.

Comment: "should not require a tool" great. However, let's suppose you inherit a system with over 500 columns on one table alone and you would like to do a bit of automated analysis

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[An Introduction to Database Normalization](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html)

Wiki: [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

[Database Normalization Tips](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139981(office.10).aspx)

> **Achieving a Well-Designed Database**   In relational-database design theory,
>   normalization rules identify certain
>   attributes that must be present or
>   absent in a well-designed database.
>   There are a few rules that
>   can help you achieve a sound database
>   design:
>
> - **A table should have an identifier**.  The fundamental rule of database
>     design theory is that each table
>     should have a unique row identifier, a
>     column or set of columns used to
>     distinguish any single record from
>     every other record in the table. Each
>     table should have an ID column, and no
>     two records can share the same ID
>     value. The column or columns serving
>     as the unique row identifier for a
>     table are the primary key of the
>     table. In the AdventureWorks database,
>     each table contains an identity column
>     as the primary key column. For
>     example, VendorID is primary key for
>     the Purchasing.Vendor table.
> - **A table should store only data for a single type of entity**.  Trying to
>     store too much information in a table
>     can hinder the efficient and reliable
>     management of the data in the table.
>     In the AdventureWorks sample database,
>     the sales order and customer
>     information is stored in separate
>     tables. Although you can have columns
>     that contain information for both the
>     sales order and the customer in a
>     single table, this design leads to
>     several problems. The customer
>     information, name and address, must be
>     added and stored redundantly for each
>     sales order. This uses additional
>     storage space in the database. If a
>     customer address changes, the change
>     must be made for each sales order.
>     Also, if the last sales order for a
>     customer is removed from the
>     Sales.SalesOrderHeader table, the
>     information for that customer is lost.
> - **A table should [try to] avoid nullable columns**.  Tables can have columns
>     defined to allow for null values. A
>     null value indicates that there is no
>     value. Although it can be useful to
>     allow for null values in isolated
>     cases, you should use them sparingly.
>     This is because they require special
>     handling that increases the complexity
>     of data operations. If you have a
>     table with several nullable columns
>     and several of the rows have null
>     values in the columns, you should
>     consider putting these columns in
>     another table linked to the primary
>     table. By storing the data in two
>     separate tables, the primary table can
>     be simple in design and still handle
>     the occasional need for storing this
>     information.
> - **A table should not have repeating values or columns**.  The table for an
>     item in the database should not
>     contain a list of values for a
>     specific piece of information. For
>     example, a product in the
>     AdventureWorks database might be
>     purchased from multiple vendors. If
>     there is a column in the
>     Production.Product table for the name
>     of the vendor, this creates a problem.
>     One solution is to store the name of
>     all vendors in the column. However,
>     this makes it difficult to show a list
>     of the individual vendors. Another
>     solution is to change the structure of
>     the table to add another column for
>     the name of the second vendor.
>     However, this allows for only two
>     vendors. Additionally, another column
>     must be added if a book has three
>     vendors.  If you find that you have to
>     store a list of values in a single
>     column, or if you have multiple
>     columns for a single piece of data,
>     such as TelephoneNumber1, and
>     TelephoneNumber2, you should consider
>     putting the duplicated data in another
>     table with a link back to the primary
>     table. The AdventureWorks database has
>     a Production.Product table for product
>     information, a Purchasing.Vendor table
>     for vendor information, and a third
>     table, Purchasing.ProductVendor. This
>     third table stores only the ID values
>     for the products and the IDs of the
>     vendors of the products. This design
>     allows for any number of vendors for a
>     product without modifying the
>     definition of the tables, and without
>     allocating unused storage space for
>     products with a single vendor.

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191178.aspx).

Answer (score 11):

The idea that you ¨shouldn´t¨use a tool is just thoughtless ideology. Mathematicians use calculators although they can do all of the calculations themselves. NORMA is good, i would start with that.

Answer (score 5):

I use [NORMA](http://www.ormfoundation.org/files/folders/norma_the_software/default.aspx) for conceptual database design. One side-effect is that it produces the schema for a properly normalized database.

Comment: +1 ... and captures the relationships, cardinality, etc in plain English and can be understood by non-techies.

Comment: I don't suppose there is a version that's compatible with Open Office?

Comment: @aslum: compatible in what way? NORMA is a Visual Studio extension. The source code is available on SourceForge - if you want some special output format, you can customize it. In particular, if Open Office uses XML formats, I know the output is driven by XSLT.

Answer (score 4):

**1:** Don't listen to anyone who tells you that normalization does not need a tool because anyone who makes such a comment does not understand the problem.

**2:** The "normal forms" are best seen as measures of the quality of a database design. For example, data schemas that are in higher normal forms have less data redundancy and are less susceptible to update anomalies - which means that your application needs less program code.

**3:** So, if normalization is essential, then what is the best way to do it?

There are many narratives about this so I will just mention two:

***Method 1: Functional Decomposition (FD)***
Now it is the case that at least one famous University Professor teaches the FD method. See this video: "[Stanford University Video on functional decomposition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDVGa53VU8s)".
Unfortunately, (and sorry Jennifer), but functional decomposition is hugely complex, prone to error and in my view, totally unworkable. (e.g. How do you figure out the right "Mega" relation in the first place?)

***Method 2: Use the NORMA tool to automatically generate 5th normal form schemas.***
The NORMA tool is **free** and it runs on the **free** version of Visual Studio 2013.
You can learn more about it on [my website.](http://ormfoundation.org)

Happy modeling.

Ken

PS I have been using the object-role modeling method for more than 20 years.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is that you should be able to fully understand how to normalize forms, for how long you will be dependent on any tools to do this for you? I would suggest you to **[study a bit about it](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm)** so that you could come up with the best solution yourself. As a developer, you will face this every now and then, and what about an interview, let's suppose where you are asked about it? And as Mitch Wheat said, normalization should not require a tool :)

Here are some more resources to get you stared:

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html

**Source: Mysql Website (Official)**

Answer (score 2):

As a beginner I used [***Relational Database Design***](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/php/relational_db_design.htm).

Believe me its great! (because it works and requires no prerequisites i.e. ideal for beginners). On page 4 it covers normalization.

Answer (score 0):

The best tutorial I've ever seen is Logical Data Modeling by Art Langer. 
Also, the accompanying pdf by Dr. Art Langer: http://dualibra.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Analysis_and_Design_of_Information_Systems__Third_Edition.pdf

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IiVq8M5DBkk&list=PL196FE5448948D9B4